# How to get more than one value of text box using in condition

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<label>Primary Skill</label> <input type="text" class="ptxt" id="pxtxid" />
<label>Secondary Skill</label> <input type="text" class="stxt" id="sxtxid" />
<input type="button" value="SAVE" class="saveDm"/>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var regex = /^[A-z]+$/;
$('.saveDm').on('click',function(){
   //$('.ptxt,.stxt').css('border-color');
   //if($('.ptxt,.stxt').css('border-color')=='#ff0000'){

    if(!regex.test($("#pxtxid").val()) && (!regex.test($("#sxtxid").val()))) {

       $('.updatePopupContainer').hide();
   }
   else{
       $('.updatePopupContainer').show();
   }

  });
```

Hi Frnds i have two check two values of the textbox if i give like "if(!regex.test($("#pxtxid").val()))" Its working for one text box how to check for more than one text box. Please give me some solution.

Comment: Please post your html code

Comment: what do you mean by more than one value in one textbox...please show your input value...

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: You need to show us the regular expression and the values that are failing.

Comment: For me your code looks absolutely correct and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **match()** to match the regex... 
See this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6gmaL7b1/1/)**

```
 if ($("#pxtxid").val().match(regex) && $("#sxtxid").val().match(regex)) {
        $('.updatePopupContainer').show();
    } else {
        $('.updatePopupContainer').hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing `&&` and `||` statements.
Your code is working fine, but you need to use `OR` instead of `AND`:

> if(!regex.test($("#pxtxid").val()) || (!regex.test($("#sxtxid").val())))

It means that you need to check that 1st textbox doesn't meet requirement OR 2nd one doesn't meet.

Here's working JSBin: http://jsbin.com/jusajiguzuqu/1/edit

As an opposite to this you could have checked if both of them meet you requirement like this (it's always better to check positivie case first as far as it's more natural and clear for human being):

> if(regex.test($("#pxtxid").val()) || (regex.test($("#sxtxid").val())))